# Extracting all minimum values from a data-set into a matrix

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a program which extracts the minimum temperatures from a data-set, `data`, for a given month, time and year.

Meaning  that a person should be able to select a time, start-/endyear and get a matrix, `lowTempsOverYears`, which should contain all the lowest-recored temperatures for january-december between two selected years at certain time.

Demonstrating what I mean I'll give a brief example. Take the two years: 1997-2001 and a time say 1200. This should give me a matrix containg the lowest tempartures recored for all months between the years 1997 and 2001. The output should be a 4x12 matrix where I have 4 different temperatures for every column which denotes the month.

You can find my program below:

```
function algo= getMiniserie(data, startYear, endYear, time)

YearInterval = startYear:1:endYear;

for month = 1:12
    lowTempsOverYears = zeros(length(YearInterval),12);
    for yearNumber = 1:length(YearInterval)

        year = YearInterval(yearNumber);

        p = extractperiod(data,year,month,time);

        if ~isempty(p)
            q = min(p);

            lowTempsOverYears(yearNumber,month) = q;
        end
    end
    algo = lowTempsOverYears;
end
end
```

The `data`variable, from which I extract my data, consists of 3 columns and 400k+ so rows.

*first column denotes the date(YYYYMMDD)

*second column denotes the time

*third column denotes the temperature

And what the `extractperiod` function does is that it, as the name would suggest, extracts all temperatures for a given month/year/time.

When I try to call my function by:

```
 >> getMiniserie(data, 1997, 2001, 1200)
```

I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/D88gy.jpg .

> > Any ideas to how I could improve my code to get my desired output?

My idea was that to make a variable which stores all the minimum values for each iteration of month.

So I initilized `lowTempsOverYears`to make it a(in this particular case wherethe start-/endyear is 1997 and 2001) `4x12` matrix. Where during the first month-iteration it stores all the minimum temperatures for january in the first column , where all the selected years are represented by the rows.

Please feel free to ask if I've omitted something from my explanation, I'll happily add to the picture.

code for `extractperiod`

```
function mdata = extractperiod(data,year,month,time)

x = year*100 + month;

k = find(floor(data(:,1)/100) == x & (data(:,2) == time));

mdata = data(k,3);

end
```

Comment: What is the jibberish you get when you try to run the function?  Is it an error or simply incorrect output?  Sometimes that jibberish can shed light on what the program is doing.

Comment: @justinwager It might've been a mistake to dismiss it. Since i'm new to matlab. This is however the output I get https://imgur.com/a/XpfqUoh , which is not the correct output.

Comment: That output shows that your code is only giving you the temperatures for December, since the first 11 columns of data are zeros.  Are you certain that the other months don't return an empty array for `p`?

Comment: Also, if you can post your code for `extractperiod`, that may also be useful to help.

Comment: @JustinWager certainly, I've now added `extractperiod`. I'm not sure if the other months are returning a empy array for `p`. How would I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first command inside your month loop is `lowTempsOverYears = zeros(length(YearInterval),12);`, you're resetting `lowTempsOverYears` to a matrix of zeros each time through the loop.  This erases the output of each previous loop.  The final time through the loop, you reset all values to zero, then fill in the 12th column.

Move the line `lowTempsOverYears = zeros(length(YearInterval),12);` outside your month loop, as shown below.

```
function algo= getMiniserie(data, startYear, endYear, time)

YearInterval = startYear:1:endYear;

lowTempsOverYears = zeros(length(YearInterval),12);
for month = 1:12

    for yearNumber = 1:length(YearInterval)

        year = YearInterval(yearNumber);

        p = extractperiod(data,year,month,time);

        if ~isempty(p)
            q = min(p);

            lowTempsOverYears(yearNumber,month) = q;
        end
    end
    algo = lowTempsOverYears;
end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If you don't mind me asking. How did you deduce that? I've been meticulously going through each line and trying to imagine it as a flowchart, to see what happens for each step. Do you have a method or was this just very trivial to spot?

Comment: I, too, was going through each line and iterating through the loop in my head.  I  sometimes write result of each loop on paper and keep track of what `lowTempsOverYears` should contain.  This often is a "slower" way of going through the code, which ensures you don't overlook a line.  As I went through the second time, I saw `lowTempsOverYears` set to zeros and realized that wasn't desired.

Comment: You can also stick a breakpoint on the line `algo = lowTempsOverYears;` and check the output of `lowTempsOverYears` manually in the Command Window.  Alternatively, remove the semicolon at the end of that line and MATLAB will show the output on each loop.